# How to handle 404 error for amazon s3 bucket in my spring boot code

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3

I have actually a problem within my spring-boot application i developed a restful api linked to an s3 bucket i've customized some exceptions but when i run my url to get an object that doesn't exsit in the console i saw this error exception in my console :

> 2019-07-25 09:06:45.733 ERROR 1 --- [-nio-443-exec-1]
>   o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for
>   servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
>   [Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The specified key
>   does not exist. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 404; Error Code:
>   NoSuchKey; Request ID: 60E24BCF6860FC66; S3 Extended Request ID:
>   DUEnMWN7YZKug74Q15uHt4Zei3+a7SxTNYzoj99O0YW58WOwvkdM1kwYpcHrGJiTrLkRLOdUL5I=),
>   S3 Extended Request ID:
>   DUEnMWN7YPOAIZADg74Q15uHt4Zei3+a7SxTNYzoj99O0YW58WOwvkdM1kwYpcHrGJiTrLkRLOdUL5I=]
>   with root cause
>
> com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The specified key
>   does not exist. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 404; Error Code:
>   NoSuchKey; Request ID: 60E24BCF6860FC66; S3 Extended Request ID:
>   DUEnMWN7YZKug74Q15uHt4ZDFSFSQSDei3+a7SxTNYzoj99O0YW58WOwvkdM1kwYpcHrGJiTrLkRLOdUL5I=)

So my question is how to perform customization to this error in 2 points:

1. Not having this error showing in the console (technically I don't mean change log parameters)
2. Handle this exception with some methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write custom exception handler to capture your exceptions and do graceful things.

```
@ControllerAdvice
@RestController
public class CustomExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(AmazonS3Exception.class)
    public final ResponseEntity<Object> handleAmazonS3Exception(AmazonS3Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
        ApiError apiError = new ApiError(UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY, ex.getLocalizedMessage(), ex.getErrors());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(apiError, UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY);
    }
}
```

Here, `UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY` is a `HttpStatus` (`org.springframework.http.HttpStatus`)

Please change the code of method `handleAmazonS3Exception(...)` based on your requirement.

Comment: thank you for your quick answer i have a ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> as a return type how can i manage this ?

Comment: I tested and it works thanks i just add an Api class and just do the @ControllerAdvice . Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid the exception completely, you can use the Aws s3 api to see if the object exists or not before trying to download it. I think the method is `doesObjectExist`. But seems like overkill if you anyway are going to download the file in case it exists.
So you can put a try-catch and if you end up catching AmazonS3Exception then check the status code and do stuff accordingly.

Comment: try, catch required when you want customized error message & if less place it is required. Else, it is better to let it be handled globally. Not only object exist, file not found. When s3 operation fails also we need to show error.